# Android detects only mock locations?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am making an app in which I want to get the users' location to show on a map. When I am running the app on a real device, it does not seem to get this location, but it gets locations if I put in mock locations using a GPS location faker. In the emulator these mock locations are also detected.

How can I get my phone to get the real location too?

Answer (score 1):

> Requesting User Permissions In order to receive location updates from
>   NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER, you must request the user's
>   permission by declaring either the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, respectively, in your Android
>   manifest file. Without these permissions, your application will fail
>   at runtime when requesting location updates.
>
> If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need
>   to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it
>   includes permission for both providers. Permission for
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION allows access only to NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Read more at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission

Comment: I already included the permissions and accepted them in my app, so that shouldn't be the problem.